# Parent-Child Component communication

Tags: angular

Which is good below mentioned method  for changing the child component properties from parent component?

**Task:**

I want to add class 'md-show' to my pop up modal component from parent component when parent component loaded

`@viewchild   decorator`

or

`document.querySelector()`

Comment: `@ViewChild` is the way to go. Avoid using `document.*` APIs as much as you can

Comment: You should consider [input binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding).

Comment: You can use `document.*` in case of angular testing

Comment: I dont understand why use any of those ways?
u can just send data to the child component whenever the parent component has change(loaded whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach than using `@ViewChild` would be:

1. Define a `shouldAddClass` property in your ChildComponent and decorate it with an `@Input` decorator.
2. Use `[ngClass]` or `[class.md-show]` in your ChildComponent Template to add the class to your HTML Element depending on the value of `shouldAddClass`
3. In your ParentComponent, create a property named `wasParentLoaded` of type boolean and set it to `false` initially.
4. In your ParentComponent template, use the bind `wasParentLoaded` with the ChildComponent's `shouldAddClass` `@Input` property via Property Binding Syntax.
5. When the Parent Component is Loaded, it's AfterViewInit lifecycle hook will get triggered. So inside `ngAfterViewInit` of the ParentComponent, you can simply change `wasParentLoaded` to `true`.

This should do the trick.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-change-on-parent-load?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) for your ref.

**PS:** This would give you the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` on the console since we're trying to change a property on the Component while Angular was performing its Change Detection. Only in the Development Mode though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one `component` inside popup component. You can use the function `ngAfterViewInit` inside popup component. Very simple :)